# Numpy masked array initialization from another array

Tags: numpy

Is there a cleaner way to initialize a numpy masked array from a non-ma, with all masked values `False`, than this?

```
masked_array = np.ma.masked_array(array, mask=np.zeros_like(array, dtype='bool'))
```

The duplicate reference to `array` seems unnecessary and clunky.  If you do not give the `mask=` parameter, the mask defaults to a scalar boolean, which prevents sliced access to the mask.

Comment: Any alternative would do the samething under the covers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just set the mask to False:

```
>>> array = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> masked_array = np.ma.masked_array(array, mask=False)
>>> masked_array
masked_array(data = [1 2 3],
             mask = [False False False],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

I saw hpaulj’s comment and played around with different ways of solving this issue and comparing performance. I can’t explain the difference, but @hpaulj seems to have a much deeper understanding of how numpy works. Any input on why m3() executes so much faster would be most appreciated.

```
def origM():
    array = np.array([1,2,3])
    return np.ma.masked_array(array, mask=np.zeros_like(array, dtype='bool'))

def m():
    array = np.array([1,2,3])
    return np.ma.masked_array(array, mask=False)    

def m2():
    array = np.array([1,2,3])
    m = np.ma.masked_array(array)
    m.mask = False
    return m

def m3():
    array = np.array([1,2,3])
    m = array.view(np.ma.masked_array)
    m.mask = False
    return m

>>> origM()
masked_array(data = [1 2 3],
             mask = [False False False],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

All four return the same result:

```
>>> m()
masked_array(data = [1 2 3],
             mask = [False False False],
       fill_value = 999999)

>>> m2()
masked_array(data = [1 2 3],
             mask = [False False False],
       fill_value = 999999)

>>> m3()
masked_array(data = [1 2 3],
             mask = [False False False],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

m3() executes the fastest:

```
>>> timeit.timeit(origM, number=1000)
0.024451958015561104
>>> timeit.timeit(m, number=1000)
0.0393978749634698
>>> timeit.timeit(m2, number=1000)
0.024049583997111768
>>> timeit.timeit(m3, number=1000)
0.018082750029861927
```

Comment: Huh, neat - I didn't pick that up from [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.array.html#numpy.ma.array), but this answer is implicitly hinted at there.